# How to move questions from the Sandbox

Tags: discussion, sandbox

We've recently noted that our questions per day stat [has gone down](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles).  We recently had somebody propose a renewal of the [Weekly Challenges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles), but as I posted there, I don't think it's the right solution.  **We have an huge resource of potential questions, all wrapped nicely up in our [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active)**

I did some research, and as of 7/3/2015, found that we have [180 unvoted, unposted, potential questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.codegolf/query/edit/331972) in our sandbox, the majority of them with 0 or 1 comments.

So, in order to help clean up the sandbox, and to increase our questions per day, I'm looking for a feasible way we can help these questions be moved or removed.

What can we do to encourage more activity in the Sandbox?

Comment: Has there been any news on the suggestion of sending a randomly picked sandbox post to chat in a feed?

Comment: No, there hasn't.  This would be a great place to post some though!

Comment: There are several posts in the sandbox that are waiting on code for controllers or whatever. Maybe volunteers to help make a controller would be helpful? I have posted a KOTH idea in there myself, but haven't taken time to work on a controller.

Comment: Also, there seems to be many people posting proposed challenges, but NOT in the Sandbox. Maybe they need some encouragement to post there instead of just in the meta.

Comment: @mbomb007 writing a controller for somebody else is a big task.  I doubt there is many people who would want to do that.  Furthermore, the challenges posted in meta are challenges that require a snippet to work (and are the exception to the rule)

Answer (score 7):

#### Add a random sandbox post feed to drop a oneboxed link into chat once a week

This was [hinted at in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22429695#22429695) so I'm adding a place for people to vote on it. I'm imagining this being maybe once a week. Raising a sandbox post in chat generally results in more feedback and more chance of the idea either being posted or identified as not possible so it can be deleted.

Thursday around 13:00 or 14:00 UTC seems like a good time based on [chat activity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: I think once a week is too little. Should be at least 2/week.

Comment: @aditsu I'll leave the post as is so people can vote on the concept, and they can upvote your comment if they want 2 per week. I've upvoted for 2 a week myself - I like the idea of potentially hitting different subsets of the community at different times of week.

Comment: I'll upvote. I also think that the sandboxed post has to have been in the sandbox for a minimum amount of time that can be decided later (maybe 24 hrs), so it's had time to be seen in the sandbox and edited by the post and other users.

Comment: @mbomb007 yes new posts should be excluded. Not sure how old they should be at minimum:

Comment: A week. _______

Comment: A month. ______

Comment: Six months (dredging up posts that need to be revived or deleted).